# Efficiency of the .NET garbage collector

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

OK here's the deal.
There are some people who put their lives in the hands of .NET's garbage collector and some who simply wont trust it.

I am one of those who partially trusts it, as long as it's not extremely performance critical (I know I know.. performance critical + .net not the favored combination), in which case I prefer to manually dispose of my objects and resources.

What I am asking is if there are any facts as to how efficient or inefficient performance-wise the garbage collector really is?

Please don't share any personal opinions or likely-assumptions-based-on-experience, I want unbiased facts. I also don't want any pro/con discussions because it won't answer the question.

Thanks

**Edit:** To clarify, I'm basically saying: No matter what application we write, resource critical or not can we just forget about everything and let the GC handle it or can't we?

I'm trying to get an answer on in reality what the GC does and doesn't and where it might fail where manual memory management would success IF there are such scenarios. Does it have LIMITATIONS? I don't know how I could possibly explain my question further.

I don't have any issues with any application it's a theoretical question.

Comment: define efficient.  without knowing how you want to measure its efficiency its difficult to answer that.

Comment: Well, if possible try to avoid relatives or if you must, compare it to a flawless manual memory management.

Comment: If you're looking for some unbiased facts, why don't you set up some tests yourself? Run through some creation and manual destruction, and then run the same program again without disposing of anything and let the GC pick it up? If you want numbers and anecdotal evidence isn't okay for you, set up the tests to get the numbers yourself.

Comment: I think you should always properly dispose of your objects. Is your question what are the performance implications of calling GC.Collect from within your code versus letting .net do it for you?

Comment: @Jonas: Compare it *on what basis*?  Often what matters isn't the total amount of time spent allocating/freeing memory but *when* it's allocated/freed - modern garbage collectors are concurrent, which means they may end up doing more work but doing it a lot faster and during "idle" times when you don't even notice the impact.  Does that count as more efficient or less?

Comment: If I beleived I had the competence to run tests that throughly and fairly judged the efficience of the garbage collector I would do it myself. But I don't think I have that competence as there are so many different scenarios you'd have to cover.

Comment: Take memory critical applications for an example where tons and I mean TONS of data is stored in memory and objects need to be disposed at a very fast rate. Will the GC be efficient enough?

Comment: Unless you're writing a real-time applicaiton, I can't think of any scenario where .net's garbage collector would be a problem, especially on modern hardware.  Unless you're talking about embedded systems, in which case there are many applications where it doesn't matter, and many where it does.. but what kind of app are you talking about here?

Comment: @Jonas - I would have to question the design of your application if it required loading tons of data into memory, and needed to dispose of it at a very fast rate.  More often than not, you can design ways to minimize the disposal of memory, such as reusing buffers and other objects and creating object pools.

Comment: Well, there is no application that's what I'm trying to say. I'm just trying to get an answer on in reality what the GC does and doesn't and where it might fail where manual memory management would success IF there are such scenarios.

Comment: @Jonas: You still haven't defined criteria for efficiency.  Does efficient mean total time spent freeing the memory?  Total work done (normalizing for concurrency)?  Some sort of performance impact on running tasks?  Peak memory usage?  Average memory usage?  Impact on end-users?  If you can't be any more specific than you already have been, then I predict close votes.

Comment: Exclude efficiency and base by limitations vs manual management then

Comment: Then I think you're doing pre-mature (very pre-mature) optimization.  You can't just take a hammer and say "Is this good for anything I want to do?"  Every tool has it's advantages and disadvantages.  For almost all apps, you will never have to worry about the gc.  Unless you have a very specific situation, there's simply nothing to worry about.  People write throusands of apps in .net without problems from gc.

Comment: You still don't understand the question. I'm not saying the GC is good or not good I'm not asking if its good or bad for every possible application you could build I am asking if it has limitations vs manual memory management - And again it's a theoretical question, I've never taken any action against the use of GC in any application I've written. At most I've manually diposed of objects because I am uncertain how the GC really works and if it will handle the disposing of my objects within a reasonable time compared to the demands of the application.

Comment: A theoretical question can only be answered theoretically.  How hard is that to understand?  Unless you have a specific scenario, nobody can give you any facts.  Garbage collection will use more resources than manual memory management, but how much, and how efficient depends entirely on the circumstances.  Without any real circumstances, you can't get a real answer.

Comment: The real circumstance would be if there is ANY circumstance where it could possibly ever be outperformanced by manual memory management in a significant matter. The scenario could be any scenario, if such scenario exists then name it if not then its all good. that article Remus posted named quite a few.

Comment: Also I would like to add that this is not about if I will EVER be affected of performance issues with the GC, in my current line of development I don't think I ever will but I think that these are important things to keep in mind for anyone who wants a good knowledge of .NET

Comment: @Jonas B, my respectful guess is that a tiny bit of study of garbage collection -- skipping algorithms and all that sh*t -- would help. Basically, the GC cleans up every object for which no object is currently holding a reference. You must help the GC by releasing references to object that you are not using in Java, C#, Ruby, whatever. In some cases it can guess -- method ends, scope no longer exists -- but in others you need to help it. This is not a GC-or-not question. It's just a question of how to work with the GC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is efficient enough for most applications. But you don't have to live in fear of GC. On really hot systems, low latency requirements, you should program in a fashion that completely avoids it. I suggest you look at this [Rapid Addition White Paper](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4215ab9e-4181-4526-823b-d364448188b2&DisplayLang=en):

> Although GC is performed quite
>   rapidly, it does take time to perform,
>   and thus garbage collection in your
>   continuous operating mode can
>   introduce both undesirable latency and
>   variation in latency in those
>   applications which are highly
>   sensitive to delay. As an
>   illustration, if you are processing
>   100,000 messages per second and each
>   message uses a small temporary 2
>   character string, around 8 bytes (this
>   a function of string encoding and the
>   implementation of the string object)
>   is allocated for each message. Thus
>   you are creating almost 1MB of garbage
>   per second. For a system which may
>   need to deliver constant performance
>   over a 16 hour period this means that
>   you will have to clean up 16 hours x
>   60 minutes x 60 seconds x 1MB of
>   memory approximately 56 GB of memory.
>   The best you can expect from the
>   garbage collector is that it will
>   clean this up entirely in either
>   Generation 0 or 1 collections and
>   cause jitter, the worst is that it
>   will cause a Generation 2 garbage
>   collection with the associated larger
>   latency spike.

But be warned, pulling off such tricks as avoiding GC impact is **really hard**. You really need to ponder whether you are at that point in your perf requirements where you need to consider the impact of GC.

Comment: That was some interesting reading and answered many of my questions, thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

I can tell you about some of the problems I've had with .NET's garbage collector.

If you're running an app that uses the server GC (e.g. an ASP.NET app) then your latency will be truly *awful*, with pauses of around a second when none of your threads can make any progress at all. This is because the .NET 4 server GC is a stop-the-world GC. Apparently, .NET 4.5 will introduce Microsoft's first mostly-concurrent server GC.

I once wrote some instrumentation code to measure latencies in a concurrent system using built-in collections like `ConcurrentBag` and kept running out of memory in 32-bit due to massive heap fragmentation because the .NET GC doesn't defragment large objects. I had to replace the array-based data structures with purely functional data structures that are scattered into millions of tiny pieces in order to avoid having anything on the Large Object Heap (LOH) that was causing the fragmentation.

I have found bugs in the GC like [this one](http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/can-you-repro-this-64-bit-net-gc-bug.html) that causes the GC to leak memory until all system memory is exhausted whereupon the heap is cleared out in one huge GC cycle that pauses not only all of your threads but even other processes (because the system has gone to swap) for up to several minutes!

Although there is a "low latency" setting in the latest .NET GC it actually just turns garbage collection off, so your program leaks memory until you get one massive GC pause. Microsoft seem to prefer workarounds like this that are tantamount to saying "write your own garbage collector if you want usable latency".

However, the .NET GC is generally very good and, when used carefully, it is possible to get good results from it. For example, I recently wrote a fault-tolerant server that achieves 114µs door-to-door latency on average with 95% of latencies below 0.5ms. That is impressively close to the state-of-the-art (see [here](http://www.a-teamgroup.com/article/cinnober-radically-reduces-latency-with-tradexpress-trading-system-version-8/) and [here](http://www.advancedtrading.com/exchanges/227701152)) given that I wrote the entire platform in F# by myself in just a few months. The network actually contributed more to the latency than the .NET GC did.

Comment: Thats some interesting reading, thanks! I'll read up on the links you posted as well :)

Comment: I can confirm that `SustainedLowLatency` really just turns off GC. This was quite a shock, after I was getting `OutOfMemoryException`s but on the whole it turned out to work well since I wanted almost no latency when I needed it, but could tolerate pauses every few minutes. I then switched back to `Concurrent` and let the GC cleanup before turning it off again.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to worry about this.

The reason is that if you ever find an edge case where the GC is taking up a significant amount of time, you will then be able to deal with it by making spot optimisations. This won't be the end of the world - it will probably be pretty easy.

And you are unlikely to find such edge cases. It really performs amazingly well. If you've only experienced heap allocators in typical C and C++ implementations, the .NET GC is a completely different animal. I was so amazed by it [I wrote this blog post to try and get the point across](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2009/03/01/the-amazing-speed-of-the-net-garbage-collector/).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *always* forget about memory allocation, regardless of whether you use a GC or not. What a good GC implementation buys you is that *most of the time* you can afford not to think about memory allocation. However there is no ultimate memory allocator. For something critical, you have to be aware of how memory is managed, and this implies knowing how things are done internally. This is true for GC and for manual heap allocation alike.

There *are* some GC which offer real-time guarantees. "Real-time" does not mean "fast", it means that the allocator response time can be bounded. This is the kind of guarantee that is needed for embedded systems such as those which drive electric commands in a plane. Strangely enough, it is easier to have real-time guarantees with garbage collectors than with manual allocators.

The GC in the current .NET implementations are *not* real-time; they are heuristically efficient and fast. Note that the same can be said about manual allocation with `malloc()` in C (or `new` in C++) so if you are after real-time guarantees you already need to use something special. If you do not, then I do not want you to design the embedded electronics for the cars and planes I use !

Answer (score 1):

Any GC algorithm will favor certain activity (ie:optimization). You will have to test the GC against your usage pattern to see how efficient it is for you. Even if someone else studied particular behavior of the .net GC and produced "facts" and "numbers", your results could be wildly different.

I think the only reasonable answer to this question *is* anecdotal. Most people don't have a problem with GC efficiency, even in large-scale situations. It is considered at least as efficient or more efficient than the GC's of other managed languages. If you are still concerned, you probably should not be using a managed langauge.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's not really a concern I just think it's something you should have a some knowledge of, I don't that is why I am asking.